# Add Some Random Movement Using Rotation

Tags: xcode, animation, uiview

I have an image of an analog metering needle, like on a VU meter, and I use the following code to make the needle swing to a desired position:

```
needleView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
// rotate 90 degrees of arc, in this case, from 90 degrees clockwise to 180 degrees:
self.needleView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90 * M_PI / 180);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Works fine.
What I want to do however, is to add some back and forth animation before the needle finally rests on the desired value, in other words, add some bounce to the needle movement. I can't figure out how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.
lq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to break up your needle swing into a pieces and apply random jitter in between the swings:

1. Create an list of uniform steps along the arc
2. Insert + or - jitter to the steps
3. Commit each as an animation of `duration / steps`

Comment: If I add more self.needleView.transform... [UIView commitAnimations]; it seems to just do the last step.

Comment: @Lauren: I would suggest building the list first and passing the list in a context object (with the "current" frame kept). You can use the `animationDidStop:finished:context:` delegate (from `setAnimationDelegate`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710939/trigerring-other-animation-after-first-ending-animation-objetive-c

Comment: From what I see I can only do two commitAnimations, the first in whatever method launches the second in animationDidStop:finished:context